# Angular Nx and NgRx : application not responding

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

Please assist, i'm learning angular nx with ngRx, and trying to implement a basic state. i have workspace and inside i have an app called company-portal with its own state. to create the state i ran the following command :

```
   ng generate ngrx company-state --module=apps/company-portal/src/app/app.module.ts  --onlyEmptyRoot
```

after i created a lib called login as follows :

```
   ng g lib shared/login --routing --lazy --parent-module=apps/company-portal/src/app/app.module.ts
```

and added a state as follows:

```
   ng g ngrx login-state --module=libs/shared/login/src/lib/shared-login.module.ts
```

then after i created a component :

```
   ng g c view/login-form --project=shared-login
```

inside the component.ts file i injected a store and added a login function as follows :

```
   constructor(private store: Store<LoginSharedState>) {}

   login() {
     this.store.dispatch(new loginActions.LoginShared());
   }
```

i have a button that execute the login function but as i click the button the application freezes(stops responding). i implemented storeFreeze and added the metaReducer, still its not working.
what should i add to make the app respond when i click the login button.

Answer (score 0):

It is not visible in your code and it is quite late to answer this question. But maybe my insights can help someone out there.

I use NgRX almost every day and the only time I see it freeze (and it is related to NgRX) is when there is an Effect which does not emit a new action and you have not configured the effect with the option `{ dispatch: false }` like for example demonstrated in the two snippets:

```js
// Freezing
createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(myAction),
  tap(() => { /* do something */ })
))
```

```js
// Not Freezing
createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(myAction),
  tap(() => { /* do something */ })
), { dispatch: false })
```

It is not necessary that there is a `tap` operator, but it is a common use case. As I said, the important thing here is, that it does not emit a new action in the stream. You can see another demo in the last snippet on the [official effects docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects).